# Ember, #if item.value inside #each, when value changed, the page did not update

Tags: if-statement, ember.js, each, helper

```
   setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('testItem', [
        Em.Object.create({name: 'aaa', hilight: false}),
        Em.Object.create({name: 'BBB', hilight: true}),
        Em.Object.create({name: 'ccc', hilight: false})
      ]);
    },
```

I set setupController in the route.

```
 changeTest: function(item){
    item.hilight = !item.hilight;
 },
```

And this action in the controller.
The handlebar code is like this:

```
{{#each item in testItem}}
    {{#if item.hilight}}
        <div>
            <h4>{{item.name}}</h1>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div>
            <i>{{item.name}}</i>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
    <button {{action changeTest item}}></button>
{{/each}}
```

The action function is executed successfully when I click the action, but page could not be updated.

So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use setter in the `changeTest` action to change the value of `hilight`.

```
changeTest: function(item){
    item.toggleProperty('hilight');
 },
```